# Can't navigate to ui-router state with URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a simple angular application using ui-router. I have a couple states for selecting and then editing information about a publisher. The relevant config:

```
            .state('select-publisher', {
                url: '/select-publisher',
                templateUrl: '/Content/superadmin/src/templates/publishers/publishers.html'
            })

            .state('publisher', {
                abstract: true,
                url: 'publisher/{id:int}',
                templateUrl: '/Content/superadmin/src/templates/publishers/publisher.html'
            })
            .state('publisher.details', {
                url: '/details',
                templateUrl: '/Content/superadmin/src/templates/publishers/details.html'
            })
            .state('publisher.ad-tags', {
                url: '/ad-tags',
                templateUrl: '/Content/superadmin/src/templates/publishers/ad-tags.html'
            })
            .state('publisher.native-ads', {
                url: '/native-ads',
                templateUrl: '/Content/superadmin/src/templates/publishers/native-ads.html'
            })
```

Inside the select-publisher state I have a big list of available publishers. Each one of them is bound to an ng-click event that triggers the following function in my controller:

```
 $scope.selectPublisher = function(publisher) {
     publisherService.setSelectedPublisher(publisher);
     $state.go('publisher.details', {id: publisher.Id});
 };
```

This works just fine and takes me to the publisher.details state and renders the proper view. At this point the URL in my browser points to `localhost:1337/superadmin#/publisher/39/details` where 39 is the ID of the publisher that I selected.

The problem is, if I refresh this page or attempt to navigate directly to it by pasting the URL into the browser from another area of the application, I am ALWAYS taken back to the `select-publisher` state. I would like to be able to configure my states such that I am able to navigate to the details state (or any other state) based on URL.

Worth noting is that I do have a catch all route defined after all of my states:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/select-publisher');
```

I'm assuming that for some reason this is being triggered but I can't reason as to why navigation works in my app using either `$state.go` as I have indicated in my controller as well as using `ui-sref directive` in my HTML templates but not through navigating directly to the URL.

Comment: What does your complete URL look like?

Comment: It's already posted in the question

Comment: maybe it's because of missing slash `url: '/publisher/{id:int}'` ?

Comment: @lujcon Wow... thanks man I can't believe I didn't spot that. Somtimes you just need a second pair of eyes. If you add that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm not here to collect points ;) I'm happy I was able to help.

Comment: But you are right - maybe it will help someone to solve similar problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it's because of missing slash url: `/publisher/{id:int}`